# Issue with pointer math in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have a question, I've started to learn pointers today and something weird came up: according to my guide, by adding 1 to the created pointer the program will go tho the next variable in the memory.
it is seen when the address of point + 1 is printed, but when I try it to print the value of *(point + 1) it just prints the address of d?

```
  int d = 5;
    int e = 12;
    int *point = &d;
    printf("\n\n%u %i\n%u", point, *point, point + 1);
    printf("\n%i", *(point + 1));
```

why is that happening?
btw I'm using codeblocks

Comment: It doesn't print the _address_ of `d`, it prints the _value_ of `e`.

Comment: Try making `d` an array of ints

Comment: Don't assume that the compiler will allocate the variable `e` immediate next to `d`. This is why the compiler is returning you garbage value instead of the value of `e`. This gives only expected result when we are using `ARRAYS`.

Comment: @Macattack Absolutely not. It prints nothing in particular. The "next variable" to `d` is not `e`. There is no guarantee that `d` and `e` are adjacents in memory. You can only do that asumption with data structures like arrays where `(&element +1)` does point to the next element (for any type of element).

Comment: Sidenote: don't print a pointer as an integer type, it isn't one, and in particular you should not assume that it has the same width as `unsigned`. `"%p"` is the correct format specifier for pointers. You'd also have to cast the pointer to `void*`, when printing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int *point = &d;
```

Evaluating:

```
*(point + 1)
```

invokes undefined behavior in C. `point + 1` is not a pointer to a valid object.

Comment: It invokes undefined behavior *in this case*.  If it was an array it would be exactly what OP is probably trying to learn to do.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is: you're advancing a pointer with

```
point + 1
```

this is undefined behavior in C because point is just a pointer to an integer **not an array of integers** and you're asking the next value... no-one (except the operating system) knows what's in the next integer cell after the one you're pointing... and so: undefined data and undefined behavior.

The following is an interactive (click on the ideone link) example for how to deal with pointer arithmetic *properly*, i.e. by advancing pointers on memory *you already control or know what's in there*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int arrayOfIntegers[] = {5,12};
    printf("First: %d, second: %d\n", *arrayOfIntegers, *(arrayOfIntegers + 1));

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/ROI1Fp

Comment: I'm using %U because I want to see the addresses in addition to the values.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the first part then. Cutting it out.

Comment: Thanks, but please take a look at the guide (3:17), it works for him:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQ2ZiXzJjE&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810&index=32

Comment: "it works" doesn't mean it will always work on every system/compiler/program you'll ever encounter. This shouldn't be done at all.. one of my friends drives while texting with both hands and until now "it worked". That doesn't mean he's not going to kill himself eventually..

Comment: Furthermore: don't follow those tutorials anymore.. the author himself wrote **"The compiler doesn't guarantee that the variables will be in order like that. I just assumed that since they were for me, they would be for the majority of people watching, but I guess I was wrong. Doing (pointer + 1) is probably getting the address of some nonsense on the stack."**. Please change your C learning video-tutorial or you'll have more problems than understood things.

Comment: Thanks, I should have read the comments by myself... any way I think that they are not bad for a beginner, and most of the time I seek for more info beside those tutorials.

Comment: A suggestion on where to start: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0131103628/?tag=stackoverfl08-20 - pick this if you really want to learn C the good way, otherwise any C for beginners book published could give you the basics (books are at least **reviewed**, unlike those tutorials)

Comment: `point + 1` is not undefined behavior. Using it is undefined behavior (as in `*(point + 1)`). C permits incrementing pointers up to one past the end of an array, and, for this purpose, single objects count as an array of one element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out: the way it has been used in the above example (incrementing and using) it's wrong and causes undefined behavior, but incrementing a pointer isn't wrong at all. As a side note also C++ uses a similar technique within containers (cfr. iterators).

Answer (score 2):

Your example is off, I think you really wanted to use an array. Perhaps, like this

```
int d[2];
d[0] = 5;
d[1] = 12;
int *point = d;
printf("%i %i %i\n", point, *point, *(point + 1));
```

Which outputs (when I run it) -

```
2271936 5 12
```

You should have read the comments on that link! On Windows 7 anyway, you can do it this way....

```
int i = 5;
int *point = &i;
int myInt = 12;
printf("%i %i %i\n", point, *point, *(point + 1));
```

Which outputs

```
2271936 5 12
```

Comment: The guide does it without an array, check it out form 3:17:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQ2ZiXzJjE&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810&index=32

Comment: Well, that guide is wrong. It works by chance. The compiler does not guarantee that local variables are stored one after the other. For example execute it here: http://ideone.com/WQikiz

Comment: @Medvednic Edited. I was able to get it to work, you really should have read the comments under the video... they gave me option 2 above, which I verified works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

This is the technical answer, as the language lawyer answer has already been given.

Your mistake is, that you misinterpreted "the next variable". What was meant is "the data contained in whatever variable happens to be next in memory", what you understood was "the next variable I defined".

These two memory places, however, have nothing, absolutely nothing to do with each other. The compiler can place *anything* next to `d`. It can be the next variable you define, but it can just as well be the return address for the function, a saved register value, some garbage produced by writing some `short` across parts of a `float`, etc. The only thing that you can not expect to happen when you access `*(point + 1)` is a segfault, because there will be at least one more return address on the stack, which means that there must be memory behind `point + 1`.

It is not without reason, that dereferencing `point + 1` invokes undefined behavior according to the standard.

---

Note, that it has some consequences that you invoke undefined behavior: The compiler is allowed to optimize *anything* away which it can prove to invoke undefined behavior or relies on it. As such, it is perfectly entitled to just throw out the second `printf()` call, or to call `system(/*command to install some nifty little program from a botnet farmer*/)`.